# res is not defined nodejs + express

Tags: node.js

i've got a problem with nodejs. I'm trying to make a httprequest to get some information, then I want to parse it in JSON file and use that file.

```
function richiesta() {
  var data_store = {}
  data_store["lista"] = []

  var uri = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films"
  var options = {
    uri: uri,
    json: true
  };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    var status = body["status"]
    var titolo = body['0']["title"]

    data_store["lista"]["titolo"] = titolo
    console.log(data_store)
    res.send(data_store)
  });
```

}

Why i got this problem? "Res is not defined"? I've tried to place response instead, but if i do this, i'll get "Response.send is not a function" so I can't understand where's the problem.

Comment: res it not defined in that scope, I assume you want to end an express request, so please post the express related code. But `richiesta` should receive: `req, res`

Answer (score 1):

Pass res as a parameter of your function, and call it inside your router callback like this:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  richiesta(res);
});
```

```
function richiesta(res) {
  var data_store = {}
  data_store["lista"] = []

  var uri = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films"
  var options = {
    uri: uri,
    json: true
  };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    var status = body["status"];
    var titolo = body['0']["title"];

    data_store["lista"]["titolo"] = titolo;
    console.log(data_store);
    response.send(data_store);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i've not the error, but when i go to "localhost:3000" i've got no response, but the console response is correct.

Comment: I would need more details please, try following nodejs express documentation before doing your own example, it is very good

Comment: This is the get request:
app.get("/titolo",(req,res)=>{
  richiesta(res)
}) and the function richiesta is the same that you've posted.

With console.log i got the correctly data, but res.send doesn't save the value of data_store, so it returns null

Comment: If you put raw data like res.send('something here')  instead of putting your data do you see the string?

Comment: It may come from the way you are displaying the information that is returned by your http request (in your browser I guess?). My guess is that you are trying to print an object, try accessing a number or a string inside data_store

Comment: For instance, instead of returning data_store, return data_store.person.firstName

Comment: If you are displaying it in your browser, you can see the actual network request by opening your devtools and checking the reponse in Network.

Comment: Mmm yes, if i put a number into data_store i display it at "localhost:3000/titolo".. so.. in data_store there's not a json file? I've tried to write res.json(data_sore) instead, but it shows me nothing again

Comment: You can do res.send(JSON.stringify(data_store)). It will turn your object into a string.

Comment: Yes, with res.send(data_store.lista.titolo) it shows me "Castle in the sky" that is the title that i wanted to visualized. But why i can't visualize it as a json format?

Comment: Basically, your browser is displaying the response of your http request. If it is able to interpret numbers and string in your response, it is not able to interpret json objects. You could parse it before sending it for example by using a combination of Object.keys, map, and injecting html so it looks nice

Comment: Damn, yes, i was sure i had make json.parse(data_store).. thanks a lot for all, you've been so patient with me. Thanks for everything, I wish you a good evening

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you don't pass the parameters to your function.

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();    

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send("get works");
})

app.post('/', ()=> {
    res.send('post works');
})

app.listen('8080', ()=> {
    console.log('server started');
});
```

Change to:

```
app.post('/', (req, res )=> {
    res.send('post works');
})
```